# How to add custom shell menu to selected .exe program or ."extension"

Tags: windows, shell, windows-explorer, bittorrent

Any windows (xp,7,8,10 x32 x64)

**1. How to add custom shell menu to selected .exe program?**

*Example:* "utorrent.exe" and "utorrent.exe.lnk"

*Action:* right-click >> shell menu >> "Open UtData"

Open UtData path(standart): "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent\"

*Result:* Open explorer window with this path

**2. How to add same p1 custom menu for all torrent associated file ."extension"?**

*Example:* "Superuser.torrent"

*Action:* right-click >> shell menu >> "Open UtData"

*Open UtData path(standart):* "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent\"

*Result:* Open explorer window with this path

Comment: Are you wanting to add a cascading menu named "shell menu"?

Comment: I whant add direct menu in "righ-click" after "open file location" (It is like "edit this in notepad"

Comment: For Q1. I mean each exe program have sub-menu that open it each type of environment, as appdata shared with this and ect by direct submenu item. So chrome.exe have it submenu like %appdata% and %downloadfolder%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Question #2, here is a sample REG file you can use.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.torrent\shell\utdata]
@="Open UtData"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.torrent\shell\utdata\command]
@=hex(2):45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,\
  00,20,00,25,00,41,00,50,00,50,00,44,00,41,00,54,00,41,00,25,00,5c,00,75,00,\
  54,00,6f,00,72,00,72,00,65,00,6e,00,74,00,00,00
```

The hex code simply means `Explorer.exe %APPDATA%\uTorrent`

**USAGE**

Copy the above lines to Notepad and save the file with `.REG` extension. Double-click the file to run it. This adds a context menu entry named `Open UtData` for `.torrent` file types.

Comment: So for Q1 maybe create new exntension "utorrent.subtorrent" that launch utorrent.exe on start, and add this or any other custom menu?

Comment: Not sure if I understand Q1. May be you can rewrite it? Does a Send To shortcut help?

Comment: I mean each exe program have sub-menu that open it each type of environment, as appdata shared with this and ect by direct submenu item.   
So chrome.exe have it submenu like %appdata% and %downloadfolder%

Comment: I guess that can be done using [advanced query syntax](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160111-00/?p=92822) with static context menu. Windows XP may not support that configuration. Easiest way is to place a script in your Send To folder, that opens the Appdata folder when invoked.